# How to prove a goal which is a conjunction of an existential and universal quantifier: Velleman's How to prove it Problem 3.32 from section 3.5

Tags: logic

I am going through Velleman's "How to prove it" and am stuck on Problem 32 from section 3.5.
It is to be proven that
If $A\subseteq B \cup C$ then $A\subseteq B$ or $A\cap C\neq\emptyset$
I think one neat way of proving this is by assuming one of the disjuncts to be wrong and the other one to be true. But I also want to find an alternate way of proving this:
I thought a good way of proving is by contradiction.
So if $\lnot (A\subseteq B \lor A\cap C\neq\emptyset)$
This is equivalent to $\lnot A\subseteq B \land A\cap C=\emptyset$ Now this can be expressed as:
$\exists x (x\in A \land x\notin B) \land \forall x (x\notin A \lor x\notin C)$
So here we have an existential and universal quantifier.
Am I right in saying that since in the first conjunct there is a $x\in A$ the first disjunct in the second conjunct is ruled out? Therefore $x\notin B\land x\notin C$ But since we assumed that $x\in A$ it has to be in either $B$ or $C$. So this is a contradiction.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. The main point that you tacitly use is:
from $$(\exists x P(x))\land(\forall x Q(x))$$one can derive$$\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x)).$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. I didn't know that. Is the rest of the reasoning correct?

Comment: 1) Neither did I, to be honest. From my part it is only naive natural deduction. But I am sure that experts or books can confirm this. 2) Imo it is fine.

Comment: Informally: $(∃xPx ∧ ∀xQx),$ so $(Px_0 ∧ ∀xQx),$ so $(Px_0 ∧ Qx_0),$ so $(∃x(Px ∧ Qx)).$

Comment: @ryang Thanks. I should have been able to figure that out myself. I have a question though. It is not in general possible to go from the third statement to the second one right? So the first statement implies the fourth one, but the fourth one doesn't necessarily imply the first one.

Comment: @eeqesri That's right.